# jQuery hide() appears to trigger another click()?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
 <div id="jch_noise_records" class="jch-noise_records">
   <span class="print_button"><a title="Print" href="#">Print</a>
   <span class="close"><a title="Close" href="#">X</a></span>
   <..more stuff in here..>
 </div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {  

  jQuery("div.jch-noise_records span.close a").click( function(e) 
  { 
      e.preventDefault();           
        jQuery('#jch_noise_records').hide();
        return false;
  });

jQuery("div.jch-noise_records span.print_button a").click( function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();                 
           var getpanel = document.getElementById("jch_noise_records");
         var MainWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=800');
         MainWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
         // MainWindow.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles/Print.css\" type=\"text/css\"/>");
         MainWindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print();  window.close()">');
         MainWindow.document.write(getpanel.innerHTML);
       MainWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
       MainWindow.document.close();
         setTimeout(function () {
             MainWindow.print();
         }, 500)
         return false; 
  });

 });
```

When the users clicks the 'close' link, to hide the div, it also clicks the 'print' link. IOW: It appears that the hide() method is firing the click() method of the print_button . Why?

Comment: How are the two elements arranged? Do they overlap each other?

Comment: Oh, I think maybe because the "print" span is not closed. [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/r9Lgf0d5/).

Comment: hide does not trigger a click.

Comment: I feel UNBELIEVABLY STUPID! Thanks!